# Marcar un Checkbox desde una BD

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, .net, asp

Estoy haciendo una pagina en ASP .NET y SQL SERVER. Lo que quiero es que al buscar una persona, haga una consulta en la BD y en base a eso seleccione las casillas. Ejemplo:
Tengo estos Checkbox

[image: Checkbox]

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="ChkNivel" runat="server">
     <asp:ListItem>NIVEL 1</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem>NIVEL 2</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem>NIVEL 2</asp:ListItem>
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

Y en la BD, tengo una tabla asi:

```
|PersonaId| Nivel|
|---------|------|
|    1    |   3  |
|    2    |   1  |
|    3    |   1  |
|    4    |   2  |
|    5    |   3  |
```

Entonces para la persona con Id=3 se seleccionara el Checkbox Nivel 1, si fuera una persona con Id=4 se seleccionar el Checkbox Nivel 2.

Realmente llevo esto que es la forma en la que busca el Id, pero estoy atorado en la parte de marcar el checkbox desde la consulta. Supongo que sería con un IF pero no se como marcarlos.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connString);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Tabla1.PersonaId, FROM Tabla1 WHERE Tabla1.PersonaId=@PersonaId", con);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PersonaId", txtPersonaId.Text);
            con.Open();
```

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

**SOLUCIÓN**

Dejo la solución por si a alguien le llega a ser util.

```
for (int i = 0; i < ChkNivel.Items.Count; i++)
{
   if (nivel == 1)
   {
      ChkNivel.Items[0].Selected = true;
      ChkNivel.Items[1].Selected = false;
      ChkNivel.Items[2].Selected = false;
   }
   else if(nivel == 2)
   {
      ChkNivel.Items[0].Selected = false;
      ChkNivel.Items[1].Selected = true;
      ChkNivel.Items[2].Selected = false;
   }
   else if(nivel == 3)
   {
      ChkNivel.Items[0].Selected = false;
      ChkNivel.Items[1].Selected = false;
      ChkNivel.Items[2].Selected = true;
   }
}
```

Comment: Con un If verificas el valor que te devuelve la BDD y lo marcas en el checkbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que un código de este estilo puede resolver tu duda, recorres el **CheckBoxList** con un foreach, evaluas el ID según tus necesidades, ocupe **PersonaId** por alguna variable en la que pases el dato, luego haces **check** en el checkbox si el Id es 4 o 3.

```
foreach (ListItem li in CheckBoxList1.Items) {
              if (PersonaId = 4) {
                  li.Selected == true
              }
              if (PersonaId = 3) {
                  li.Selected == true
              }
          }
```

Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias, eso me ayudo a resolver mi problema